# Limit every user to his own home folder only

Tags: linux, ssh, file-permissions

i have a linux server which users connect to with SSH.
my users only upload and download content from their `/home` folder.

Basicly, I want them to be limited to see and use only their home folder.

I read that it might not be a good idea to do so, since they nead read premissions to run programs and scripts, but again: they are only downloading\uploading content to their home dir.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9):

Follow [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/229) guide to configure your SSH server to chroot your users.

Essentially, use the `ChrootDirectory` and `ForceCommand` rules for `sshd_config` to limit certain users or groups (`Match Group` or `Match User`) to SFTP and a specific directory.

This requires use of the rule `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` as well, unless the `ChrootDirectory` contains all files for a real chroot environment (like a `/dev` directory with some basic devices)

---

A different possibility would be to disable shell login. SCP and SFTP might still work for them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also install webmin on the server http://www.webmin.com/ 
with webmin you will be able to set limits as to what the users can do and access. Its pretty easy as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at bash, but Google led me to a link regarding [restricted bash for user accounts](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/restrict-linux-users-to-their-home-directories-only/). Hope It helps.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.